# How to connect ads titles from Google/Facebook to my wordpress website page?

Tags: wordpress, web, google-ads-api, facebook-ads-api

I ran into a problem. I do have ... lets say 40 ads on facebook and google adwords to promote my business in my country. My website is running on wordpress. Is there any way to connect my ads with my website, so website page will show title of advertisement, which customer clicked? Lets say I do have 2 different titles, I love cats, I love dogs. If customer click on title I love cats, on website page should be the same title he clicked via ad. Same applies for I love dogs title. Is anything like this possible to realize? Any help will be appreciated.

P.S. Sorry for my english, its not really great. Tried my best.

Comment: Why is this question getting minuses? I dont get it, just need help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic ads. That way adwords will autocreate the headlines based on your website but you need to be careful because with dynamic ads you don't set keywords and you have to closely monitor your search queries to exclude irrelevant traffic or low converting keywords.